# Pass element refrence to self from DOM back to view model

Tags: html, angular, angular-directive, angular6

Known feature:

`<div #element (click)="myMethod(element)"></div>`

this passes the div back to the VM for manipulation, etc.

What I'm looking for is short hand to pass an element to a method without declaring a template variable. It could look like this:

`<div (click)="myMethod($self)"></div>`

This would be helpful in cases where creating elements in an `ngFor` stops you from giving every element a variable name or in cases where using a third party library that sends its own `$event` and the element ref is missing. Does anyone know of any way to do this?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with angular, but i know with traditional HTML + vanilla JS you can do `<div onclick="myMethod(this)"></div>`

Comment: In angular, passing `this` will give the method a reference to the view model, not the element itself unfortunately.